# xml mapping error

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, xml-parsing

i am working on project , in that there is one xml file (IDE Eclipse Indigo).
I am facing a problem with sincle line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookingConfirmRQ xmlns="http://www.expediaconnect.com/EQC/BC/2007/09"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Authentication username="yyyyyyyy" password="xxxxxxxx" />
<Hotel id="<hotelId/>" />
<BookingConfirmNumbers>
    <BookingConfirmNumber bookingID="<bookindId/>"
        bookingType="<bookingType/>" confirmNumber="<confirmNumber/>"
        confirmTime="<confirmTime/>" />
</BookingConfirmNumbers>
</BookingConfirmRQ>
```

Here near *< Hotel id="< hotelId/>"/>* am getting error like_

*The value of attribute "id" associated with an element type "Hotel" must not contain the '<' character.*

i search it , checked jar's, reformatted still getting error, can sombody help me?
thank u.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore validation of XML from eclipse windows-preference-validation menu and this way if you don't want to change you can avoid this error

Comment: This document is not a valid Xml document meaning that any Xml compliant parser will choke on it. I don't see how ignroing this error helps?

Comment: from is question it is clear that he don't want to process this file and as this file is placed by someone else so neither he can change that file nor he can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values should only contain literal text:

```
<Hotel id="134" />
```

Comment: can i use like "<hotelId/>" this? because it is previously coded by developer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the angle brackets in the value of the attribute like this:

```
     <Hotel id="&lt;hotelId/&gt;" />
```

Same with the all the other attributes. The angle brackets are on the list of reserved characters that have to be escaped in XML.

Unless you do that, the XML is not well-formed and nothing will process it. Turning off validation - i.e. validation against a DTD or schema - will not help here. The XML has to be well-formed before it can be parsed.

That said, the XML looks very odd, as if you're including whole XML-elements as the value of attributes which is just wrong. So even if you fix the escaping problem this XML may not say what you meant.